# How to assign light and dark mode to Google maps recenter button?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using Google Maps SDK to embed maps on my application. I have also enabled maps recenter icon using:

```
extension DashboardVC: GMSMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    if !change{
        googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        ColorLocationButton()
    }
        change = false
}
func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {
    googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
    change = true
    return false
}
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMyLocation location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
 }
}
```

How can I add light and dark mode to this button rendering from Google Maps itself?

Answer (score 0):

*First Add a View and Add the Image inside a View*

**Then Make The Outlets on Your Controllers**

```
@IBOutlet weak var recenterView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var hamburgerImage: UIImageView!
```

*if Your View On the Google Maps View Must add these Line of Code in Your viewWillAppear*

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
    self.googleMapView.bringSubviewToFront(self.recenterView)
    recenterView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapOnRecenter = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(recenterTheMap(gesture:)))
    tapOnRecenter.delegate = self
    recenterView.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnRecenter)
    // Setup The Recenter View For Corner Radius and Shadow
     recenterView.clipsToBounds = true
    recenterView.layer.cornerRadius = recenterView.frame.size.width / 2
    recenterView.layer.shadowColor  = UIColor(ciColor: .gray).cgColor
    recenterView.layer.shadowRadius = 12 
     }
```

*your Recenter Button Code*

```
 @objc func recenterTheMap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   
  googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 15)
     
  }
```

*Do not Forget the Add Gestures Delegate*

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

*Detect Light or DarkMode Through This Delegate Method*

```
   override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
            if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
              
            recenterView.tintColor = .white
            
            }
            else {
                
                recenterView.tintColor = .black
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

*Here is Your Code For Current Location*

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   location: CLLocation = locations.last!
 }
```